# time lose on heavy html

Tags: performance, node.js, express

I use caching for big pages and in log file got:

```
GET /myUrl 200 25ms - 444.83kb
```

But in browser actually I got html only after 4 seconds. So it is much greater than `25ms`. I underline that it is time getting html only without loading js and css. 
On local machine it works ok. But on production not very fast machine I have such time lose. Why?
I have noticed that for pages less than `300 kb` the difference between logged load time and actual load time is not so big and time load is satisfactorily.

I rednder html like this:

```
html = loadFromFile(url);
res.send(html)
```

Comment: What is loadFromFile ? Are you reading file synchronously.

Comment: What does the network panel in the browser developer tools say? If node says it renders in 25ms but you get the html in 4s it seems you have a slow internet connection.

Comment: as it looks you are reading the file in synchronous mode, meaning that its blocks everything until it get that file.. as a practice in node.js is considered "not nice" when you have all this asynchronous functions at your disposal.. 
i suggest that you use `node-static` if you serve static content only.. or better yet, read articles/tutorials for expressjs, and what it can do with jade/ejs and `res.render`

Comment: @GeoPhoenix ok I will better read file asynchronously. It is not only static content, it is just prepared html for page that loads for more than one minute. It is cache.

Comment: @AndreasHultgren I agree. Big files like 400 kb loads slow. I tested the same page on server. Requesting it directly from server and there time in log and time measure for getting html the same.

Comment: @user568109 `loadFromFile` converts url like `/abc/de` to `_abc_de` and get file `./cache/_abc_de`, read it (now async) and return as ready html response. It loads cache for heavy pages.

Comment: Are you storing cache files on disk ?

Comment: The only variant I found is to reduce html size to 300 kb and less. Just make page smaller removing unnecessary  information.

Comment: @user568109 yep on disk

Comment: consider placing `app.use(express.compress())` at the top of your middleware stack for express 3.x